# How can we change the audio tracks in video .mp4 format in web?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, video.js, tizen-web-app

I have video file of .mp4 format. It has multiple audio tracks in-built in it.

VideoJs & ReactPlayer is not detecting those audio tracks. Is there any way to target particular audio track. ??

How to target those audio tracks and how can we change them ?
Is there a player for this?

Answer (score 2):

MP4 is played directly by the browser, only Safari supports multiple audio tracks in MP4. If you use HLS then multiple audio tracks are supported by Video.js via media source extensions.